# How to make my web api public instead of localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, model-view-controller

I have created an ASP.NET MVC project and added a controller that contains different APIs (inherits from ApiController)

The APIs by default are in localhost. My question is how to make those APIs public? What are the steps please?

Should I deploy the entire project? or only the APIs? 
I don't know the steps actually and need some help

Comment: You have to deploy the entire project, because the APIs you have created are also part of your solution. 
It is better to create a new Web API Project for API related functions as it will help you to avoid dependability between the projects.

Please refer this link for deployment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41445470/how-to-build-and-publish-net-mvc-and-web-api-projects-to-their-different-folder